# Unrecognized statement type. (near "FOR" at position 0)

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to insert billion rows into a SQL table using phpMyAdmin but I get this error:

```
Unrecognized statement type. (near "FOR" at position 0)
```

Here is my code:

```
FOR @i in 1 ..1000000000 do 
BEGIN

INSERT INTO test VALUES (@i, "First", "Second", "Long lorem ipsum here!")

END
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [MySQL doesn't appear to support `FOR` loops](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/flow-control-statements.html). What documentation are you following?

Comment: I've found this on the internet. I want to insert a billion rows at once. How can I do this?

Comment: You found **what** on the Internet? I suggest you read the MySQL documentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a procedure to run a loop, as below code show:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS WhileLoop;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE  PROCEDURE   WhileLoop()

BEGIN

set @start = 0;
set @end = 1000000;
WHILE @start < @end
DO
# LOOP QUERY & INSERT NEW RECORD
INSERT INTO test VALUES (@start, "First", "Second", "Long lorem ipsum here!")


SET @start = @start + 1;
END WHILE;       
END$$
call WhileLoop();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use While Loop Instead Of For, as below code show:**

```
Set @i = 1

While(@i <=1000000000) 
BEGIN

  INSERT INTO test VALUES (@i, "First", "Second", "Long lorem ipsum here!");
  set @i = @i+1;

END
```